# How to automatically attach a file to JupyterLab?

Tags: python, file, attachment, jupyter-lab

I am trying to automatically attach pictures to JupyterLab. Every day, a new picture gets taken by a remote camera, and I want that picture to go to Jupyterlab for processing using Python. Is there a way to automatically attach the picture (through Python or otherwise)?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by 'attach'. For example, you could put the images on a disk or server, so they have a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) of some kind, and access them from a JupyterLab session (or a Python script or whatever). Can you elaborate a bit? Do you have code you're already using on the images? Is something specific not working?

Comment: I don't really care how they are connected, as long as the images can be accessed through JupyterLab, and I don't have to do anything everyday.

Comment: Okay, so where are the images stored? Can your notebook read them from there? Is it just a question of finding the latest image in a pile of images? It's very hard to tell what you're trying to do if you don't share any code or frame the question as a programming problem. There are lots of ways to get data into a Python program.

Comment: The images are stored in a file on a windows laptop. I need to be able to call the latest image every day into my script and execute the script automatically.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate where and how the files are stored, and how exactly you're using JupyterLab. It sounds like you can simply read the images from the laptop's storage, e.g. using `pillow.Image.open(fname)`... but the details depend on things like the file location, file names, image type, and so on. And [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).